# Typescript enforce that string value is one of the object values

Tags: typescript

I have this constant declaration:

```
export const Actions = {
    VIEW: 'view',
    EDIT: 'edit',
};
```

and lets assume now I have a function like below:

```
// how to ensure action variable below is string of value either view or edit
function insertAction(action: string): void {
  console.log('trust me i inserted the action');
}
```

My goal is to allow action parameter to have values only `view` | `edit` and understand this *dynamically, so please do not suggest using union solution because I know that already and is not fit to my purpose.

I have tried signature like the one below

```
function insertAction(action: typeof Actions[keyof typeof Actions]
```

but it does not work.

I can still call the function `insertAction('whatever')` and ts compile does not fail neither the linter.

In my package.json am using typescript version 4.4.2 with PHPStorm Editor and nextjs

```
    "typescript": "^4.4.2"
```

Comment: `typeof Actions[keyof typeof Actions]` should work *if* you declare `Actions` with the `as const` modifier. Eg: `export const actions = {...} as const;`. Can you let us know if that works?

Comment: @CRice thank you that worked!!! https://ibb.co/vZmMs2n I will read more about the `as const` typescript syntax was not aware of it. Without `as const` this was not working. Also am open to any solution if there are more elegant ones although this achieves now what I intend to and am happy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not use enum and assign `action:EAction`?

That should look like this:

```
export enum EActions {
    VIEW = 'view',
    EDIT = 'edit',
}
```

your function

```
function insertAction(action: EAction): void {
  console.log('trust me i inserted the action');
}
```

will show you type error:

```js
insertAction('whatever'); // will show you error
```

Argument of type '"whatever"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EAction'.

Use your EActions:

```
insertAction(EAction.VIEW);
```

It would be easier to read in my opinion.

Example:
[JS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwKIEEDGMCWEicA3gFByVwBqAkhgOoC8A5AG77ADuLANBVQwARWgBUmcFsAAm+GHzIBfMmQBmyRHkLF8iAM7BYuAkQAUAQy1EAXJmPaAlLbYR800gJxE9EADbAAOl8IAHNTFhgoZD14VGA4fAT9QxgZOBgAC3jLE0QWBwBuJRVdAyMrRHCuDPNUtkN8grgAema4LnxfXzg9DIguOABPCGQEKChoEuTy3NNsCoC6RkKWtogAayA)

Comment: That was my first idea, I like it. I see the other way with `as const` syntax, but I don't really like the whole typeof stuff, maybe because I don't use it very often.

Comment: Thanks this look more elegant as you entioned avoids "typeof keyof" long syntax. Iwill test it out in playground,. If the value of `Eaction.VIEW` is `view` instead of enum int than is perfect alternative to the other solution with `as const`. Upvoted thanks

Comment: @KristiJorgji glad it was helpful for you , if that answer your need I appreciate if you mark this as answer.

Comment: I tested now and works as expected. 1. I cannot use a different value 2. the value of Eaction.VIEW is the string on right side of `=` so 'view' . Both are valid. Thank you chose your answer as solution considering is slightly more elegant than the as const one and using typeof TYPE [keyof tyopeof TYPE]

Answer (score 1):

Your current solution:

```
function insertAction(action: typeof Actions[keyof typeof Actions])
```

should work, as long as you declare the `Actions` object using the [`as const` modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#readonly-and-const):

```
export const Actions = {
    VIEW: 'view',
    EDIT: 'edit',
} as const; // <-- note the assertion here.
```

---

This works because by default, when you declare an object without an explicit type, eg:

```
export const Actions = {
    VIEW: 'view',
    EDIT: 'edit',
}
```

TypeScript can see that the *variable* is constant, and cannot be reassigned. However since it is assigned an object with potentially *mutable values*, TypeScript will infer for that object the type:

```
{
  VIEW: string;
  EDIT: string;
}
```

What you want is for the value type not to be `string`, but the exact *literal string type* for `"view"` and `"edit"`. Using the `as const` modifier informs TypeScript that the values of the object *will not be mutated*, and so it will then infer the stricter, literal string type for those values.

Then, since the value types are the exact strings `"view"` and `"edit"` respectively, using `typeof Actions[keyof typeof Actions]` will produce the union type `"view" | "edit"`, exactly what is needed for your parameter type.